# Automatically extension of the layout when i add a new textview

Tags: layout

i have a **big** problem. I am working on a project at the university (in Germany). I have a plain text and a button (look at my code below).
Whenever I enter sth. into the plain text and click the button, I want it to be listed and the layout must be **expand**.

Did somebody have any idea???

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.alime.beispieltextview1.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/frage1"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:text="Zutat: *"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/zutatensuche"
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_light_frame"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/zutatensuche"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/zutatensuche"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/suchbutton"
                android:text="+"
                android:background="#FF2FC10F"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="108dp"
            android:id="@+id/layoutlist">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/zutat1"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/zutat2"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/zutat3"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/zutat4"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/zutat5"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/zutat6"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button8" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        /*Die eingegebenen Zutaten werden nach betätigen der Button aufgelistet*/
        Button zutatbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        zutatbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zutatensuche);
                String text = e.getText().toString();
                TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zutat1);
                TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zutat2);
                TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zutat3);
                TextView t4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zutat4);
                TextView t5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zutat5);
                TextView t6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zutat6);

                if (t1.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    t1.setText(text);


                } else if (t2.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

                    String text2 = e.getText().toString();
                    t2.setText(text2);

                } else if (t3.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

                    String text3 = e.getText().toString();
                    t3.setText(text3);

                } else if (t4.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

                    String text4 = e.getText().toString();
                    t4.setText(text4);

                } else if (t5.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

                    String text5 = e.getText().toString();
                    t5.setText(text5);

                } else if (t6.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

                    String text6 = e.getText().toString();
                    t6.setText(text6);

                }

                e.setText("");
            }

        });
    }
}
```